# Namespaced controller routing in Rails 3 without resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I'm migrating an application from Rails 2 to Rails 3.
We have multiple namespaced controllers with different namespaces.
As they are not RESTfull I don't want to use resource routing, instead I would like to have an old Rails 2 like *match ':controller/:action'* that picks up namespaced controllers.

In my routes.rb I have

```
# Install the default route as the lowest priority.
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))', :controller => /[^\/]+\/[^\/]+/
```

*rake routes* reports

```
/:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))          :controller#:action
/:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))          (?-mix:[^\/]+\/[^\/]+)#:action
```

Still a request to */config/companies/index* fails

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/config/companies/index"):
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to get namespaced routes with dynamic segments? When I try to use *namespace* and a *match* with a dynamic segment together it throws an error.

```
:controller segment is not allowed within a namespace block
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the problem.
Config is a reserved constant in Rails, it points to RbConfig. My match condition actually works but tries to call RbConfig::CompaniesController which of course does not exist.

When I tried to add

```
match '/:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))', :controller => /config\/[^\/]+/
```

the error was

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant RbConfig::CompaniesController)
```

Solution: rename the app/controllers/config -> app/controllers/configuration (and the views folder) and add a redirect to the routing to handle legacy links.

```
match '/config/*path' => redirect("/configuration/%{path}")
```